# Converting subclass to base class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, type-conversion, subclass

I am working on a problem in which we have a binary search tree made of nodes.  The node's attributes consist of string, pointer to left node, and pointer to right node.  I have a class called TransactionNode that is a subclass of node.  TransactionNode has an int (for amount sold) as well as the same attributes from node class.  I have a function called findBiggest that looks for the highest amount sold from TransactionNode and returns a reference to that TransactionNode.  My problem is how do I convert something that is from the node class to TransactionNode? (I am avoiding changing the nodes in the binary search tree to TransactionNodes)

```
TransactionNode & BST::findBiggest()
{
    TransactionNode * rightSide;
    rightSide = this->mpRoot;

    while (rightSide != nullptr)
        {``
           //find biggest transaction
        }

     return rightSide;

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you need to check if an object pointed to by a base class pointer is of the derived class type, you use dynamic_cast

In your case you could try inside your while loop:

```
TransactionNode* txnNode = dynamic_cast<TransactionNode*>(rightSide);
if (txnNode != nullptr)
{
     int amtSold = txnNode->GetAmountSold();

}
```

You may also consider having a virtual method in the base class and rely on polymorphism. Usually that is a preferred way over dynamic_cast. However, it may be that your Node class is too high level and does not need to support a "GetAmountSold()" method, but that is something you can decide.